# Filestash s3 integration [ a drag and drop GUI for file management on server ]

Tags: linux, file, user-interface, file-manager

I have installed Filestash on my Linux server and everything is working perfectly. but I have doubts in some of the settings, I am mainly looking for s3 integration, anyone please let me know the usage of the bellow mentioned option in s3 Backend. Please refer to the screenshot attached

please help me...

[Please find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKzcg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think, right now anyone can access your files from the bucket from

> http://myipaddress/files/

To keep an authentication these options can be used. I have not tried it yet. After trying I will add it here.